# RMI with class files works but not with jars

Tags: java, rmi, executable-jar

When I test an RMI client and server with the class files it works without any issue on two different machines. Now when I do the same thing with a jar the client fails to connect to the RMIRegistry on the server. Then when I test with the jar on the same machine, the client can connect to the server (even over the network ip and not localhost).

I suspect this has something to do with the RMI registry, but i'm a total novice at RMI, so I have no clue...

I create an RMIRegistry like so:

```
rmiregistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(ServiceConstraints.REGISTRY_PORT);
rmiService = (RmiSubjectService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this,
                    ServiceConstraints.REGISTRY_PORT);
rmiregistry.rebind("RmiService", rmiService);
```

The client connects like this:

```
remoteService = (RmiSubjectService) Naming.lookup("/" + host + ":"+ port + "/RmiService");
```

The error I get on the client when running with a jar:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.2.132; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at ch.uzh.ifi.group10.client.Client.subscribe(Client.java:148)
        at ch.uzh.ifi.group10.client.Client.main(Client.java:242)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown S
ource)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown S
ource)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Changing from class files to JAR files can't possibly cause a network error. Are you sure nothing else changed in the network?

Comment: yes I tried one immediately after the other without changing any parameters except the execution environment, that's why I'm stumped. I should note that this error only happens after some time (the code hangs on Naming.lookup()). Also, the weird thing is that I have also come across the situation where nothing happens (no error, just hanging) even though I leave the thread open of 5 min. This might be because of a timeout parameter in RMI.

Comment: No, it is a timeout condition in your network. Changing to the JAR files had nothing to do with it, it was just a coincidence. There is no connection timeout in RMI unless you set it yourself, there is just the default, which is the *system* default, not Java's, and it is around 70 seconds. If you can't form a connection within a couple of seconds there is something seriously wrong with your network.

Comment: it seems weird that running class file has never failed although I have tested it numerous times. I'm not quite sure, but could the codebase have something to do with it? Could it be that the client cannot download the server stub?

Comment: If that was so you would get a `ClassNotFoundException`. Is `192.168.2.132` the IP address you expect to see? and can you ping that IP address from the client host? If not, see item A.1 on the RMI FAQ.

Comment: Yes that is the IP of the server. I also checked so see if the port that RMI is running on is open, which it is. I don't quite know what this means, but all the other times I tried the same case I did not get an error, the thread was just hanging on the lookup call. I also tried the same thing with getRegistry and then getting the server stub, which would be the same as Nameing.lookup() and the program could get the registry but started hanging when retrieving the server stub.

Comment: I just tried running the server on a linux machine and the client on windows and got this error running the client on windows: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: create. On linux there is no error running the client as well as when the server is run on windows. The client extends UnicastRemoteObject and the error happens when super() is called

Comment: I also tried to get a `ClassNotFoundException` by adding a bogus RMI service name at the end of the url passed to Naming.lookup(). The result was the same as in the case were a valid url was passed. I did not get an Exception as I would have expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did turn out to be the network. Specifically it was that I didn't realize that my firewall was blocking the socket, so I could not connect.